# parallel processes with arguments

Tags: python, google-app-engine, popen

i'm working on google app engine, and at first did something like this:

```
queue = multiprocessing.Queue() 

cs = multiprocessing.Process(name='control_service', target=control_service_func, args=(queue,))
cs.daemon = True

m = multiprocessing.Process(name='machine', target=machine_func, args=(queue,))
m.daemon = True

cs.start()
m.start()
```

but then realized that google engine doesn't support multiprocessing module..

so I need some other tool..
I saw that for parallel processes, I can use Popen but all examples are something like:

```
Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])
```

which run a command as if it was from the shell...

I need to create 2 parallel processes that run,each, his own function  (target in my example, which get as an argument a queue)

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

App Engine has its own processing model -- which includes its own queues (two kinds, actually: "push" queues, and "pull" ones).  Use a push queue (simpler, and managed for you more fully by the App Engine back-end) and **modules** to serve the requests on that queue - and depending on your work load you may transparently end up using multiple servers &c (App Engine will take care of this scaling for you).

You gain some (automatic scaling and structuring), you lose some (fine grained control on what processes are running where).  If the tradeoff is not right for you, App Engine (or other PaaS set-ups) may not be best for you -- you may want a lower lever of abstraction, an IaaS set-up, such as Google's **Compute** Engine instead.